# Can't enable performance level for RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to enable perfromance logging for a `RemoteWebDriver` in Java Selenium. I have this code:

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.addArguments(arguments);
  chromeOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(acceptInsecureCerts);

  DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilites = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
  logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
  desiredCapabilites.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
  desiredCapabilites.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

  return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), desiredCapabilites);
}
```

When trying later on to access the performance logs like this:

```
driver.manage().logs().get("performance")
```

I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found
  (Session info: headless chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'tr-glass-gather-crawler-workerjrsgs-pod-mfk8b', ip: '172.21.62.217', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.120+', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 95.0.4638.69, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 95.0.4638.54 (d31a821ec901f..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.vRBs3j}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:36139}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://172.21.62.217:4444/ses..., se:cdpVersion: 95.0.4638.69, se:vnc: ws://172.21.62.217:4444/ses..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.21.62.217:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: d595d868024953284123f1c300378445
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteLogs.getRemoteEntries(RemoteLogs.java:81)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteLogs.get(RemoteLogs.java:77)
        at com.wayfair.glass.gather.worker.crawler.WFPartnerCrawlerFacadeImpl.navigate(WFPartnerCrawlerFacadeImpl.java:110)
        at com.wayfair.glass.gather.worker.plugin.impl.CrawlerGatherPlugin.internalRun(CrawlerGatherPlugin.java:93)
        at com.wayfair.glass.gather.worker.plugin.impl.CrawlerGatherPlugin.run(CrawlerGatherPlugin.java:69)
        at com.wayfair.glass.gather.worker.plugin.PluginRunner.run(PluginRunner.java:45)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:819)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:803)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:346)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at com.wayfair.glass.gather.worker.GlassGatherWorkerApplication.main(GlassGatherWorkerApplication.java:12)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

This seems to work if I use `ChromeDriver` instead of `RemoteWebDriver`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently changing this:

```
desiredCapabilites.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
```

To this:

```
desiredCapabilites.setCapability("goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs);
```

Fixed it